# Difference between sleep(1) and while(sleep(1))

Tags: operating-system

I have the following piece of code while looking for sigchild code. In the code below 50 children are created and the parent process waits in sigchild handler until all 50 children are destroyed.

I get the expected result if I use `while(sleep(1))` at the end of main, however if I replace it by `sleep(1)`, the parent gets destoyed before all child processes terminate.

```
int l=0;
/* SIGCHLD handler. */
static void sigchld_hdl (int sig)
{
    /* Wait for all dead processes.
     * We use a non-blocking call to be sure this signal handler will not
     * block if a child was cleaned up in another part of the program. */
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0) {
            printf("   %d",l++);
    }
    printf("\nExiting from child :: %d\n",l);

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

        struct sigaction act;
        int i;

        memset (&act, 0, sizeof(act));
        act.sa_handler = sigchld_hdl;

        if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0)) {
            perror ("sigaction");
            return 1;
        }

        /* Make some children. */
        for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            switch (fork()) {
                case -1:
                    perror ("fork");
                    return 1;
                case 0:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        /* Wait until we get a sleep() call that is not interrupted by a signal. */
        while (sleep(1)) {
        }
      //      sleep(1);
            printf("\nterminating\n");
        return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the following piece of code while looking for sigchild code. In
>   the code below 50 children are created and the parent process waits in
>   sigchild handler until all 50 children are destroyed.

No, it does not. waitpid WNOHANG will fail if there is nobody *exited*. And there is no guarantee all the children exited (or will exit) during execution of the handler.

Even with mere sleep(1) there is no guarantee any child will manage to exit, but in practice most of them will.

sleeping is a fundamentally wrong approach here. Since you know how many children you created, you should wait for all of them to finish and that's it. For instance you can decrement a counter of existing children each time you reap something and wait for it to go to 0.

Depending on how the real program looks like, it may be you don't want the handler in the first place: just have the loop at the end, but without WNOHANG.

I also have to comment about this:

> /* Wait for all dead processes.
>        * We use a non-blocking call to be sure this signal handler will not
>        * block if a child was cleaned up in another part of the program. */

You can't mix a signal handler and waiting on your own. You risk snatching the process from the other code waiting for it, what happens then?

It's a design error. fork/exit behaviour has to either be unified OR decentralized.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)

> Return Value
>
> Zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the number of seconds
>   left to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler.

So I guess without the `while` bit, the sleep is being interrupted, hence that process ending quickly